# Http streaming in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using:

```
<WebBrowser Height="387"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" Name="Camera1"  />
```

I'm have and button start in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="startButton" Content="Start" Width="75" Height="20" Margin="4,0,0,0" Click="startButton_Click" />
```

In xaml.cs class I have method `startButton_Click`:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    Camera1.Navigate("http://96.10.1.168/mjpg/1/video.mjpg?timestamp=1470753862585");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please specify what problem behavior you are actually seeing. See this guide on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Good luck and happy hacking!